# Bus error in simple C program

Tags: c, bus-error

I have the following simple program. And I am running "program file.txt" from the command line and getting "Bus error" with no output. I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(char *arg[])
{

    FILE *file = fopen(arg[0], "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you print out the value of arg[0], suppose the type of main is

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

and the argv[0] is the name of process, the argv[1] is first argument.

Comment: No, I also had trouble printing out arg[0].

Comment: so, change you main type to int main(int argc, char* argv[])

Comment: Okay, thank you! Worked perfectly! Changed to your suggestion and used argv[1] and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

The prototype for the c entry function is

```
int main(int argc, char *arg[]);
```

So with your prototype you are actually trying to dereference an int to  passing to fopen

Try this instead

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard prototype for `main()` should look like this:

int main(int argc, char * argv[]);

You declared your `main()` with just one argument, `argv`.  But the system is passing a count of arguments as the first argument.

When you specify a single argument (the file `file.txt`), `argc` is set to 1.  But your program is trying to use the integer 1 as a `char **`.  That gives the bus error.

Here is an edited version of your program that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    FILE *file;

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: myprogram <filename>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file.\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    exit(0); // status 0 to signal no error
}
```

Changes:

- I added `#include <stdlib.h>` to get a declaration of `exit()`.
- I check the number of arguments and print a Usage: string if it's not right.
- I made the error messages print to `stderr` instead of standard output.
- I changed `return 1` to `exit(0)` to make it clear that the program is exiting successfully.

Answer (score 0):

`argv[0]` contains the application name. Try using `argv[1]` instead.

Comment: in this case `arg` holds the number of argument passed.